# How do you pass an object through a function using a pointer?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, object, vector

I wanted to pass an object - which is also a vector - through a function using pointers.

I believe the issue arises on line 75 (transaction(&user, userID);) where I attempt to pass the object "user" through to the function "transaction".
I don't believe the classes are relevant so I left them out. Thank you so much in advance. Here is the source.cpp code:

```
void transaction(vector<Customer *> &user, int userID);

void newAccount(vector<Customer*> & user, int userID);

void intr(vector<Customer*> & user, int userID, int account, int interest);

void loans(vector<Customer*> & user, int userID, int account, int loan);

int main()
{

    vector<Customer> user(3);

    user[0].setname("Josh");
    user[0].setID(1);
    user[0].bank[0].setbalance(100);
    user[0].bank[1].setbalance(101);
    user[0].bank[0].setoverdraft(200);
    user[0].bank[1].setoverdraft(201);
    user[0].accounts = 1;
    user[0].setpin(1202);

    user[1].setname("John");
    user[1].setID(2);
    user[1].bank[0].setbalance(102);
    user[1].bank[0].setoverdraft(202);
    user[1].accounts = 0;
    user[1].setpin(1203);

    user[2].setname("Jack");
    user[2].setID(3);
    user[2].bank[0].setbalance(103);
    user[2].bank[0].setoverdraft(203);
    user[2].accounts = 0;
    user[2].setpin(1204);

    int input;
    int userID;
    int pin;
    int account;
    bool menu = true;

    //Menu
    while (menu)
    {
        cout << " - Enter '1' to display all customer names and ID's." << endl;
        cout << " - Enter '2' for further transactions." << endl;
        cout << " - Enter '3' to make a quick withdrawal of " << char(156) << "10 from an account." << endl;
        cout << " - Enter '4' to exit." << endl;
        cin >> input;

        // List
        if (input == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++)
            {
                cout << "[Name: " << user[i].getname() << "\t" << "ID: " << user[i].getID() << "]" << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        // Transactions
        else if (input == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter Customer ID: ";
            cin >> userID;
            cout << "Enter pin: ";
            cin >> pin;
            if (pin == user[userID].getpin())
            {
                transaction(&user, userID);
            }
            else { cout << "Pin invalid." << endl; }
        }
        // Quick withdrawal
        else if (input == 3)
        {   
            cout << "Enter Customer ID: ";
            cin >> userID;
            cout << "Enter pin: ";
            cin >> pin;
            cout << "Enter the account you wish to make a withdrawal from: ";
            cin >> account;
            if (pin == user[userID].getpin())
            {
                if (account <= user[userID].accounts)
                {
                    if (user[userID].bank[account].getbalance() - 10 <= -user[userID].bank[account].getoverdraft())
                    {
                        user[userID].bank[account].withdraw(10);
                    }
                    else { cout << "Insignificunt funds. Overdraft limit (" << char(156) << user[userID].bank[account].getoverdraft() << ")" << endl; }

                }
                else { cout << "That account does not exist." << endl; }
            }
            else { cout << "Pin invalid." << endl; }
        }
        // Exit
        else if (input == 4)
        {
            menu = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
    }

    void transaction(vector<Customer *> &user, int userID){...}
```

ERROR DESCRIPTION: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing wrong arguments to the `transaction()` first parameter takes **reference to vector of customer pointer**

```
std::vector<Customer*> &user
```

but you are passing an **address of vector of customer**

```
vector<Customer> user(3);
transaction(&user, userID);
```

you should change 
`vector<Customer>` 
to 
`vector<Customer*> user(3)`.
or
change 
`void transaction(vector<Customer *> &user, int userID);`
 
to  
`void transaction(vector<Customer> &user, int userID);`

the same goes for other functions if you are doing the same thing.

about the error, are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: The second option, changing the `transaction` function is by far the better idea, assuming `Customer` is not a base class for a family of customer types. Even then it should be passed by reference.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately I come across this error when changing void transaction(vector<Customer *> &user, int userID); to void transaction(vector<Customer> &user, int userID); Description more than one instance of overloaded function "transaction" matches the argument list

Comment: @JoshuaTalbot Have you declared more than one `transaction` function or are you including a library that already has a transaction function? Did you perhaps not update a forward declaration of `transaction`?

Comment: Also when changing vector<Customer>  to vector<Customer*> user(3) I get this error: transaction(std::vector<Customer,std::allocator<_Ty>>,int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<Customer *,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<Customer,std::allocator<_Ty>>'

Comment: @JoshuaTalbot Do not do that. Only do one of the above options. Do not do both. Unless you want to take a crash course in manual memory management do not go the `vector<Customer *>` route. It is much more complicated.

Comment: @user4581301 I have not declared more than one transaction function nor do I have a library that has it. I did forget to update my forward declaration but when I fixed that I got no error but running it crashed it.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the heads up. I wont haha.

Comment: @JoshuaTalbot crash means this question is resolved and now you have a new problem: Find the logic error that is somewhere in your code. The easiest way to find it is to [run your program in the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that came with whatever development environment you use. The debugger will halt the program as soon as it crashes allowing you to check the state of the program (the variables and call stack or back trace) to see why it crashed. If you get stuck, provide your code and the information from the debugger in a new question.